# If $|G|=12$ and $G$ has no elements of order 2 in its center, then $G$ is isomorphic to $A_4$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, normal-subgroups

What I have to prove is that if $|G|=12$ and $G$ has no elements of order 2 in its center, then $G$ is isomorphic to $A_4$.

I know that the center of $A_4$ is trivial, so if there were to be an element of order 2 in the center of $G$ then it wouldn't be isomorphic to $A_4$, but I'm not clear on how to prove that if $G$ doesnt have such element then it is actually isomorphic to $A_4$. I thought of using the fact that the center is a normal group, but I can't seem to find a way to use it. Any help on how to start would be appreciated.

Comment: Of course you could just manually check the center of the other two non-abelian groups of order $12$.

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ has a normal $3$-Sylow subgroup $Q$, then you can show that it must be centralized by an element of order $2$, hence $G$ has an element of order $2$ in the center.

The other possibility is that you have $4$ Sylow $3$-subgroups. In this case the action of $G$ on the $3$-Sylows embeds $G$ into $S_4$, hence it follows that $G$ is isomorphic to $A_4$.